# glitter/sparkle effect on hair

Tags: materials, particles, shaders, lighting

I saw a couple of pictures and renders on Instagram lately where mostly the hair is sparkling and very glossy on spots where the light is. I’m new to blender and I tried to add glare in composition but it didn’t do anything.

I tried to max out the glossy slider on the rig itself but it doesn’t do anything. how to get it to shine like this? Is it the light source? or the rig/hair itself? (the image is not mine)

[image: sparkle effect]

---

I added the shaders and suggested by [BlenderMaster15](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/146160/blendermaster15) and it came out like this: [image: fail] how do I get rid of this? The texture is corrupted or something? (the "cube" fragments in the hair)

Comment: Is this particle hair or hair cards (textured planes)?

Answer (score 1):

For that glitter effect, try adding a really small noise texture to the hair's roughness socket, and add a colorramp node to the noise texture. This way, you can control how small the glitter is.[image]
[image]