Light Dependent Texture
I'm very much so a beginner at certain blender concepts, especially nodes and textures. So I ask kindly for your patience. I have a model that I want to add a shiny speckled texture to all over, that only shows up in areas most saturated by light when the viewer is looking at it. I am making an avatar and I found another one with this example :

And I've just about given up with trying to research for how to do this elsewhere lol any help is much appreciated.
ive been experimenting with the textures and i have a few ideas for the texture itself, but i dont know how to get it to follow the light source/only show up the light source like in the picture provided. much thanks

We don't know what render engine you use. I'm not sure how to achieve that, but any glistering effect is tricky. It's similar to fireflies (overexposed pixels) which you usually want to minimize. I'm not saying it's impossible, though.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45358/how-to-create-a-glitter-texture/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99251/cycles-material-a-kind-of-glitter https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144441/suspended-glitter-in-clear-material https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261190/glitter-sparkle-effect-on-hair

Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?
